# Split and replace elements in a list and convert to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to convert data, a list, to a csv file.

The list called *data*

```
['time\ntimestamp\nrecordtime\nlat\nlong\nalt\nspeed\ncourse\nverticalAccuracy\nhorizontalAccuracy\nlocTimeStamp\naccelerationX\naccelerationY\naccelerationZ\nHeadingX\nHeadingY\nHeadingZ\nTrueHeading\nMagneticHeading\nHeadingAccuracy\nRotationX\nRotationY\nRotationZ\nmotionYaw\nmotionRoll\nmotionPitch\nmotionRotationRateX\nmotionRotationRateY\nmotionRotationRateZ\nmotionUserAccelerationX\nmotionUserAccelerationY\nmotionUserAccelerationZ\nen0\npdp_ip0\nDeviceOrientation\nState', '2014-11-19 08:57:45.696;1;1;52.33705;4.843468;8.319668;20.44;93.05875;6;5;1416383865;0.0806427;-0.4734802;-0.7419281;-16.14367;27.67606;-15.92525;53.06408\n52.48165;26;0.04704554;0.9128267;0.4871223;0.1783603;0.2536548;0.6368796;0.07435028;0.8879893;0.4615479;-0.1116289;0.1097959;0.04115437;0.0.0.0;10.167.22.1;1;0','2014-11-19 08:57:45.696;1;1;52.33705;4.843468;8.319668;20.44;93.05875;6;5;1416383865;0.0806427;-0.4734802;-0.7419281;-16.14367;27.67606;-15.92525;53.06408\n52.48165;26;0.04704554;0.9128267;0.4871223;0.1783603;0.2536548;0.6368796;0.07435028;0.8879893;0.4615479;-0.1116289;0.1097959;0.04115437;0.0.0.0;10.167.22.1;1;0']
```

The csv file, called *csv*, is supposed to look like this:

```
time,timestamp,recordtime,lat,long,alt,...,State
2014-11-19 08:57:45.696, 1, 1, 52.33705, 4.843468, 8.319668,..,0
2014-11-19 08:57:45.696, 1, 1, 52.33705, 4.843468, 8.319668,..,0
```

In other words, `'\n'` got to be replaced with `','` and `','` with a newline and on these lines `';'` needs to be `','`. I do not know where to begin.

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

Comment: `str` objects have a `split` command, e.g. `'a\nb\nc'.split('\n')` would result in `['a','b','c']`.

Comment: Thanks, that link helped; but it was not complete for me.

Answer (score 2):

Let `l` be your list.

```
>>> header = l[0].split('\n')
>>> rows = [s.split(';') for s in l[1:]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> header[:3]
['time', 'timestamp', 'recordtime']
>>> rows[0][:3]
['2014-11-19 08:57:45.696', '1', '1']
>>> rows[1][:3]
['2014-11-19 08:57:45.696', '1', '1']
```

I'll leave the task of file I/O to you as that's the easy part of the question. You will have no problem to find the docs of the `csv` module and we're not here to write your complete code.

Comment: Perfect, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have commas in your data - those are list indices that are either separated by a new line or by a semi-column, so all you need is to split each element on those to get individual cells, and in the end write everything to a standard CSV format which you can do with the built-in `csv` module:

```
your_list = ['time\ntimestamp\nrecordtime\nlat\nlong\nalt\nspeed\ncourse\nverticalAccuracy'
             '\nhorizontalAccuracy\nlocTimeStamp\naccelerationX\naccelerationY'
             '\naccelerationZ\nHeadingX\nHeadingY\nHeadingZ\nTrueHeading\nMagneticHeading'
             '\nHeadingAccuracy\nRotationX\nRotationY\nRotationZ\nmotionYaw\nmotionRoll'
             '\nmotionPitch\nmotionRotationRateX\nmotionRotationRateY\nmotionRotationRateZ'
             '\nmotionUserAccelerationX\nmotionUserAccelerationY\nmotionUserAccelerationZ'
             '\nen0\npdp_ip0\nDeviceOrientation\nState',
             '2014-11-19 08:57:45.696;1;1;52.33705;4.843468;8.319668;20.44;93.05875;6;5;'
             '1416383865;0.0806427;-0.4734802;-0.7419281;-16.14367;27.67606;-15.92525;'
             '53.06408\n52.48165;26;0.04704554;0.9128267;0.4871223;0.1783603;0.2536548;'
             '0.6368796;0.07435028;0.8879893;0.4615479;-0.1116289;0.1097959;0.04115437;'
             '0.0.0.0;10.167.22.1;1;0',
             '2014-11-19 08:57:45.696;1;1;52.33705;4.843468;8.319668;20.44;93.05875;6;5;'
             '1416383865;0.0806427;-0.4734802;-0.7419281;-16.14367;27.67606;-15.92525;'
             '53.06408\n52.48165;26;0.04704554;0.9128267;0.4871223;0.1783603;0.2536548;'
             '0.6368796;0.07435028;0.8879893;0.4615479;-0.1116289;0.1097959;0.04115437;'
             '0.0.0.0;10.167.22.1;1;0']

# On Python 3.x use open("output.csv", "wt", newline="") instead
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:  # open output.csv for writing
    writer = csv.writer(f)  # create a CSV writer
    for element in your_list:  # iterate over each element in your_list
        # turn each line into cells by splitting first by a new line, then by a semi-column
        # then write the resulting cells to the CSV using our CSV writer
        writer.writerow([v for e in element.split("\n") for v in e.split(";")])
```

The resulting `output.csv` will contain:

```
time,timestamp,recordtime,lat,long,alt,speed,course,verticalAccuracy,horizontalAccuracy,locTimeStamp,accelerationX,accelerationY,accelerationZ,HeadingX,HeadingY,HeadingZ,TrueHeading,MagneticHeading,HeadingAccuracy,RotationX,RotationY,RotationZ,motionYaw,motionRoll,motionPitch,motionRotationRateX,motionRotationRateY,motionRotationRateZ,motionUserAccelerationX,motionUserAccelerationY,motionUserAccelerationZ,en0,pdp_ip0,DeviceOrientation,State
2014-11-19 08:57:45.696,1,1,52.33705,4.843468,8.319668,20.44,93.05875,6,5,1416383865,0.0806427,-0.4734802,-0.7419281,-16.14367,27.67606,-15.92525,53.06408,52.48165,26,0.04704554,0.9128267,0.4871223,0.1783603,0.2536548,0.6368796,0.07435028,0.8879893,0.4615479,-0.1116289,0.1097959,0.04115437,0.0.0.0,10.167.22.1,1,0
2014-11-19 08:57:45.696,1,1,52.33705,4.843468,8.319668,20.44,93.05875,6,5,1416383865,0.0806427,-0.4734802,-0.7419281,-16.14367,27.67606,-15.92525,53.06408,52.48165,26,0.04704554,0.9128267,0.4871223,0.1783603,0.2536548,0.6368796,0.07435028,0.8879893,0.4615479,-0.1116289,0.1097959,0.04115437,0.0.0.0,10.167.22.1,1,0
```

Comment: Worked as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this code should solve your problem:

```
import csv
def csv_writer(data, path):
    with open(path, "a",newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(data)

data = ['time\ntimestamp\nrecordtime\nlat\nlong\nalt\nspeed\ncourse\nverticalAccuracy\nhorizontalAccuracy\nlocTimeStamp\naccelerationX\naccelerationY\naccelerationZ\nHeadingX\nHeadingY\nHeadingZ\nTrueHeading\nMagneticHeading\nHeadingAccuracy\nRotationX\nRotationY\nRotationZ\nmotionYaw\nmotionRoll\nmotionPitch\nmotionRotationRateX\nmotionRotationRateY\nmotionRotationRateZ\nmotionUserAccelerationX\nmotionUserAccelerationY\nmotionUserAccelerationZ\nen0\npdp_ip0\nDeviceOrientation\nState', '2014-11-19 08:57:45.696;1;1;52.33705;4.843468;8.319668;20.44;93.05875;6;5;1416383865;0.0806427;-0.4734802;-0.7419281;-16.14367;27.67606;-15.92525;53.06408\n52.48165;26;0.04704554;0.9128267;0.4871223;0.1783603;0.2536548;0.6368796;0.07435028;0.8879893;0.4615479;-0.1116289;0.1097959;0.04115437;0.0.0.0;10.167.22.1;1;0','2014-11-19 08:57:45.696;1;1;52.33705;4.843468;8.319668;20.44;93.05875;6;5;1416383865;0.0806427;-0.4734802;-0.7419281;-16.14367;27.67606;-15.92525;53.06408\n52.48165;26;0.04704554;0.9128267;0.4871223;0.1783603;0.2536548;0.6368796;0.07435028;0.8879893;0.4615479;-0.1116289;0.1097959;0.04115437;0.0.0.0;10.167.22.1;1;0']
for d in data:
    csv_writer(d.replace('\n',',').replace(';',',').split(','),'data.csv')
```